# DATE TIME difference between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014, I need to calculate total time difference between start time and end time in HH::MM::SS format of all records

Sample data:

```
ID      StartTime               EndTime
---------------------------------------------------
5287    2017-11-04 12:38:04     2017-11-04 12:40:45
5288    2017-11-04 17:08:28     2017-11-04 17:08:34
5289    2017-11-04 17:08:41     2017-11-04 17:11:41
```

(2:41  --time difference OF ID  5287

0:6   --time difference OF ID  5288

3:0   --time difference OF ID  5289
)

OUTPUT: 00:05:47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something, like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime,EndTime), ''), 114)
```

And if you want total sum:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(8), DATEADD(second, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartTime,EndTime)), ''), 114)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @apomene

Answer (score 1):

try something like : 
 `SELECT DATEDIFF(year, expression_one, expression_two) AS DateDiff;`

the part `year` is the interval. It can be any of the following:

- quarter, qq, q = Quarter
- month, mm, m = month
- dayofyear = Day of the year
- day, dy, y = Day
- week, ww, wk = Week
- weekday, dw, w = Weekday
- hour, hh = hour
- minute, mi, n = Minute
- second, ss, s = Second
- millisecond, ms = Millisecond

Answer (score 1):

**Test table**

```
create table timeTest
(
Id int,
StartTime datetime , 
EndTime datetime
)

select * from timeTest
```

[image]

```
select convert(varchar(5),sum(DateDiff(s, StartTime, 
EndTime)/3600))+':'+convert(varchar(5),sum(DateDiff(s, StartTime, 
EndTime)%3600/60))+':'
+convert(varchar(5),(sum(DateDiff(s, StartTime, EndTime)%60)))  as 
[hh:mm:ss]
from timeTest
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]